# Is $\overline{\{x: f(x) < a\}} = \{x: f(x) \leq a\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Is $\overline{A} =\overline{\{x: f(x) < a\}} = \{x: f(x) \leq a\} = B$?

Since $B$ is closed and contains $A$, $\overline{A} \subset B$ as $\overline{A}$ is the smallest closed subset containing $A$. It remains to show $B \subset \overline{A}$. Let $x \in B$. If $f(x) < a$, then we are done. Now suppose $f(x) = a$. There exists $x_{n} \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that $x_{n} \rightarrow x$. However, I cannot guarantee that $f(x_{n}) < a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you are right, to see a counterexample take $ f(x,y)=a$.

Comment: If you get the idea to make it empty, then you can modify it very easily just take $ f(x,y)=a +x^2$. You can also play around and make it non empty too.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ and $a=0$. Then one set is empty and the other is a singleton.